# Determine referenced dll file version in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# solution, which references a dll I created from a different C# solution.

It is easy enough to determine my solution's product version with Application.ProductVersion. However, what I really need is a way to determine the file version of the exe and the dll separately, within my program. I want to display the dll and exe's file versions in my About dialog. What would the code look like to do this?

Answer (score 27):

The simplest way is if you know a type in the referenced assembly:

```
AssemblyName name = typeof(MyCompany.MyLibrary.SomeType).Assembly.GetName();
```

[Assembly.GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bk16ya.aspx) returns an [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) which has a [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) property indicating the version of the assembly.

Alternatively, you can get the assembly names of all assemblies referenced by the executing assembly (i.e., the .exe):

```
AssemblyName[] names = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

Comment: Thanks; I figured there had to be a simple way of doing this in .NET but I hadn't been able to find it. When I was looking for a solution, I think what threw me was GetName()... I didn't even look at it, because I assumed it would just return a string or something.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the easiest solution is this:

```
var version = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeType)).GetName().Version;
```

where SomeType is a type you know for sure that is defined in that particular assembly. You can then call .ToString() on this [version object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) or look at its properties.

Of course, this will blow up in a huge fireball the moment you move your type into another assembly. If this is a possibility, you will need a more robust way to find the assembly object. Let me know if this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

The [**`AssemblyInfo`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo_members.aspx) class has all this information, so you just need to get a reference to the assembly in your code.  For example:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName.Version.ToString()
```

You can get the other assemblies in the project in various ways, for example

`var assemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();`